# Laravel Passport not working correctly on Chrome

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, laravel-passport, laravel-5.5

I've just run a fresh Laravel 5.5 install alongside Passport, following the frontend quick-start with the default auth scaffolding.

Created a user account and a personal access token.
Added the needed middleware (CreateFreshApiToken).
Accessing `'/api/user` displays the correct information on first page refresh.

In Chrome, if I then refresh the page a SECOND time, I am logged out and when I try to login again I get a 419 Error.

In Firefox, if I do the same, everything works perfectly.

What could be causing this error?
I am currently running this on localhost on Wamp, if I push it to production could this cause a similar error?

Comment: Check your browsers for any errors in the console/network tab and place them in here

Comment: Apart from the 419 when I try to login, there are no errors. Just found out that the csrf token is changing on each page refresh, but only after I've tried to login.